# Clipboard listener register twice when Cut

Tags: c#, forms, listener, clipboard, cut

Only when I cut something, it registers 2 times. How can I avoid this? Is there a way to tell if I copied or cut something?

This is my code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AddClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool RemoveClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);
private const int WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE = 0x031D;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            if (m.Msg == WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString("update in clipboard"));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried checking m.wParam and m.lParam for the message, may be There's a clue.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to call `Convert.ToString()` on a string...

Comment: Where do you call `AddClipboardFormatListener`? Is it possible your application gets registered twice?

Comment: I add AddClipboardFormatListener(this.Handle); once in Form1_Load

Comment: You're monitoring the clipboard. It doesn't know why it was updated. It may not be your app that caused the update. Why is cut or paste important? Are you monitoring the wrong thing?

Comment: Some applications open the Clipboard multiple times. Mostly when cutting contents. You probably haven't tested it with a PhotoShop layered image, a CorelDraw composition or an Excel chart. The count can go up to 20+ messages. Btw, you should return `m.Result = (IntPtr)0;` as the return value and move `base.WndProc(ref m);` to the end of the method. About the Copy/Cut: `wParam` *might* know (even if it should be 0). You'll have to verify it yourself. If set to `0x12`, it could be a Copy, if set to `0x0E`, it could be a Cut. Provided as is. No guarantees.

Comment: When I double tap Ctrl+C I want something to happen. Not also when I cut something.

Comment: I can't figure out how to use wParam...

Comment: Is it double-tap Ctrl+C Windows-wide or in your app? Windows-wide I'd use AutoHotKey if it was something just for me. If it had to be in code I'd look into keyboard hooks.

Comment: I figured it out! if (Convert.ToString(m.WParam) == "4" || Convert.ToString(m.WParam) == "13") means if (copy text || copy files)